# How many integer solutions are there

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> How many integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ in $(ab)/(a+b)=3600$?

My attempt:

$(ab)/(a+b)=3600$

= $ab=3600(a+b)$ where $a+b\not=0$

= $ab=3600a+3600b$

=$ab-3600a-3600b$

=$(a-b)3600$

=$3600a-3600b$

=$(a-3600)(b-3600)$

=$ab-3600a-3600b+3600^2$ where $a+b\not=0$

I am not really sure if this is correct. I was just doing this for fun after I was reading this in some mathematical book. It just explained about a few things not much. I was trying this for a while now and I am not sure what to do. Can someone please help me with this solution?

Comment: @AndréNicolas It has 225 positive divisors and 225 negative divisors. That would be 450 divisors together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as $ab-3600a-3600b=0$, and then as $(a-3600)(b-3600)=3600^2$.

So $a-3600$ must be a divisor $s$, positive or negative, of $3600^2$, and $b-3600$ must be $t$, where $t=\frac{3600^2}{s}$. Conversely, if we let $s$ be any divisor of $3600^2$, and let $t$ be as above, then $a=3600+s$, $b=3600+t$ is a solution.

Now we ask how many divisors $s$ of $3600^2$ are there? Note that $3600=2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2$, so $3600^2=2^8\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^4$.

Thus $3600^2$ has $(9+1)(4+1)(4+1)$ positive divisors, and an equal number of negative, for a total of $(2)(9)(5)(5)$.

**Another way:** The following start is less symmetrical, so I like it less. We can rewrite our equation as 
$$b=3600+\frac{3600^2}{a-3600}.$$
So again we want $a-3600$ to be a divisor of $3600^2$.

Comment: You are welcome.